# Is Dreamweaver Get eXtension compatible with Tridion 2013?

Tags: content-manager

We are using Dreamweaver Get eXtension for our current Tridion 2009 SP1 platform. We have started migration of our Tridion 2009 SP1 to Tridion 2013. As far as I can determine, the Dreamweaver Get eXtension (DGX) is certified to work on Tridion 2009 and 2011, according to the author of the program. Does any one know whether this extension will work on Tridion 2013?

Thanks!

Comment: I'd be pretty confident that it will work, the source code is also online so if you need to recompile with another version of the tridion libaries that's also possible

Comment: ok thanks, let me give a try and if any issues yes can look back the source code to fix.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To be honest, I have not tested it - but this code has worked with no changes since 2009 GA, and given I use only public APIs I strongly doubt it will break in any way.

Give it a try and let us know? I'll gladly look into fixing it if needed, but again I strongly doubt it's broken.

PS: I also didn't test it for 2009 SP1, 2011 GA, 2011 SP1 or 2013 GA, and it does work on those versions...

PPS: I assumed you were upgrading to 2013 SP1, but I realize now that's not clear from your question. I have used the DGX on 2013 GA with no issues, and I'm pretty confident it will work on SP1 for the reasons mentioned above.

**UPDATE**

I went ahead and tried deploying the DGX on a new 2013 GA instance (didn't have an SP1 instance at hand). These are the steps I followed and it worked perfectly.

1. Download the [DGX](http://www.sdltridionworld.com/community/extension_overview/dreamweaver_get_extension.aspx) from Tridion World
2. Unblock the zip file (open properties, click unblock)
3. Drag-and-drop the binary dll into c:\windows\assembly
4. Add the required `functionSource` configuration to Tridion.ContentManager.Config
5. Try using it

**I did not need to recompile it.**

I didn't have to restart anything because I had not yet loaded anything in Tridion, so when I opened my browser and went to Tridion it loaded the new configuration. I could preview and publish with no errors.

I think step #2 is going to keep on biting people forever.

Comment: ok, I will try and see how it goes. thanks

Comment: we are using 2013 GA and not SP1

Comment: You'll be fine, it's known to work on 2013 GA. Reach out if you run into trouble

Comment: And btw, I guess this might be late in your upgrade process... but I'd consider implementing SP1 rather than GA

Comment: yes, we are planning for SP1 soon. please help on below,
1. We are running 2013 CM on WINDOWS2012Server(64 Bit)
2. I see Tridion DLLs under "\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL"
3. We have Our wrapper DLL on top of GetExtension DLL which is compiled for 64bit(.NET 4.0)
4. To make GetExtension DLL compatible, I downloaded source code and created GetExtension DLL for 64bit(.NET 4.0)
5. I installed both DLLs in CM server though GACUTIL (Wrapper DLL and GEtExtension DLL)
6. I see installed dlls on "\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_64"
7. Still getting error 'JScriptException: Expression 'Get

Comment: Did you register them on Tridion.contentmanager.config (I guess you did for the wrapper you have). Might be worth posting as a question, I'll give it a quick try tomorrow

Comment: Yes, I have registered wrapper dll in Tridion.ContentManager.Config

Comment: See update to my answer

Comment: thanks, I followed your instruction again and it started working. Only thing is we are using 2009.1.2.0 version of DreamweaverFunctionExtensions where it has push and few more methods, from where can I download source code for this version of dll?

Comment: You should probably ask that to the person that provided you this version - I never wrote a 2009.1.2.0 version :) (though push is included in this one, just not documented)

Comment: Ohh ok, I was able to get the code from Reflector from our old dll. Some of the code was failing, so I upgraded that code to 2013 compatible library and everything is fine now. Thanks again.